# Orientationchange only works the first time

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working on my app for android built using jquerymobile and phonegap.
I'm testing orientationchange to verify that jquerymobile manages layout accordingly with lanscape or portrait mode. I don't want any custom action at orientationchange event, I only want that jquerymobile css (media settings) works for me and reset the items on the html5 page.

But It seems that orientationchange event is fired only first time. To see that, I create this simple js:

```
$(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
navigator.notification.alert(jQuery.event.special.orientationchange.orientation());});
```

And I discovered that the alert message is shown only at first orientation change event(from portrait to landscape). After this first message no other alert appear, so I argue that the event is not more fired.
I'm missing something, maybe on configuration or Android manifest? thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this happen in an AVD I created for 2.3.3 (Android).  As a test I setup a new AVD (2.2) and this issue did not happen in the new AVD.  Also, I deployed app to my physical phone (2.3.4) and tested, issue did not happen on the phone either.

I recreated the AVD in question and used the Google API 10, instead of Android 2.3.3. Issue happened under the google AVD as well.  So there is either a bug in the 2.3.3 AVD or within Android 2.3.3 itself.

Hope this information is useful.